# HSSFWorkbook truncation while reading number from xls file in Scala

Tags: java, scala, hssfworkbook

I am facing a problem with `HSSFWorkbook`. I have an XLS file containing some numeric values. When i try to convert the XLS file to CSV format by `HSSFWorkbook.java`, i always gets the numeric field values truncated that results into a type of `Double` value.
I do not know, what is the best solution to this problem. If anyone has worked on this, please help in getting rid of this issue...

Comment: Add what you have tried till now

Comment: please add the code what you tried so Far ???